# How to get full remote path in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, path

Let's say I have a virtual `R:` drive that actually goes to `\\filesrver\share`.

How can I get the full remote path of a file, expanding net shares?

(`R:\Scripts\s.ps1` --> `\\fileserver\share\Scripts\s.ps1`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
get-item R:\Scripts\s.ps1 | 
              select  @{n="path";e={ "$( get-psdrive $($_.psdrive) | 
                  select -expa displayroot)$(split-path $_ -noqualifier)" }}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution, also works for local paths (it doesn't change them of course):

```
function Get-FullRemotePath($path) {
    # Attempts to expand net shares
    if (!(Test-Path $path)) { return $path }

    $fileObj = Get-Item $path
    $remotePath = (Get-PsDrive $fileObj.PSDrive).DisplayRoot
    if ($remotePath) {
        $path = $remotePath+(split-path $fileobj -noqualifier)
    }
    return $path
}
```

Not a one liner though.